# Issue with MenuInflater

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

This the error I'm a currently getting:

```
The method inflate(int, android.view.Menu) in the type MenuInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, com.example.thebasicstweekz.Menu)
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method
```

Comment: Are you using eclipse? At the bottom there should be a tab tat says logcat, that contains your errors. Can you see it?

Comment: camn ypu show full code?? Are you using ActionBarSherlock??

Comment: We don't really need any more code to tell your problem. You are passing in a `com.example.thebasicstweekz.Menu` when you must pass in a `android.view.Menu`. It says right in your error.

Comment: What is ActionBarSherlock? Add me on skype and tell me some plz so i can get help easier in future? :) I got it, thanks for the help guys, damn so nice community..

Answer (score 0):

have a try with getSupportMenuInflater

```
getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

instead of

```
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

import for Menu - it should be `android.view.Menu`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the DDMS perspective?

Have you tried Window > View search for "Android" or "LogCat" ?

Thanks